# Modify colorbar color ticks and color for a map in ggplot

Tags: r, dictionary, ggplot2, colors

I am attempting to map AI-related job postings over the past year using ggplot, but I need to reverse the default color scheme so it goes from light blue (#52ABF0) to dark blue (#142E47). Also, I have some zip codes that are outliers (856 job postings in one area and 516 in another). Most job postings lie around the 0-300 range. Therefore, I also need to change the markers to be 0-100, 100-200, 200-300, and 300+ instead of evenly spaced out.

I have tried using scale_fill_gradientn and scale_fill_gradient2, but for some reason, ggplot skips right over those commands when I try to graph.

```
    [install.packages('zipcode')
    library(zipcode)
    library(tidyverse)
    install.packages('maps')
    library(maps)
    install.packages('viridis')
    library(viridis)
    install.packages('ggthemes')
    library(ggthemes)
    devtools::install_github("hrbrmstr/albersusa")
    install.packages('albersusa')
    library(albersusa)

    fm<-Export <- read.csv("ai_job_postings.csv", header=FALSE)
    colnames(fm) <- colnames(Export) <- c("job_id", "post_date", "fill_date", "time_to_fill", "company", "vertical", "location", "salary",
                      "city", "state", "zip", "county", "latitude", "longitude", "region_state")

    fm.zip<-aggregate(data.frame(count=fm$job_id),list(zip=fm$zip,county=fm$county),length)
    fm<- merge(fm.zip, zipcode, by='zip')

    us<-map_data('state')


ggplot(fm,aes(longitude,latitude)) +
  geom_polygon(data=us,aes(x=long,y=lat,group=group),color='gray',fill=NA,alpha=.35)+
  geom_point(aes(color = count),size=2.5,alpha=.25) +
  xlim(-125,-65)+ylim(20,50) +
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), 
      panel.background = element_blank(), 
      panel.grid.minor = element_blank(), 
      axis.ticks.y=element_blank(), 
      axis.ticks.x=element_blank(), 
      axis.text.x = element_blank(),
      axis.title=element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank(), 
      legend.title=element_text(size=25),
      legend.text=element_text(size=14),
      plot.caption = element_text(size=12, hjust = 1.3)) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = "#52ABF0", mid = "#3874A5", high = "#142E47", midpoint = 200, guide="colorbar", limits=c(0,900)) +
  labs(color="AI Postings", caption=paste0(sum(fm$count), " AI Job Postings Nationwide June 2018 - June 2019"))]
```

Comment: We don't have your data, so we can't run your code, and we can't see any output. Without a [mcve] all anyone can do is guess

Comment: It looks like you mapped to `color`, not `fill`, so try `scale_color_gradient2()`.

Comment: @aosmith That was it! Thanks!